# How to call unity C# functions from Android plugin?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I know how to call android functions from unity using "AndroidJavaClass" and "AndroidJavaObject"

but what I dont know and want to know is -
How can I call functions present in the unity code from the android java plugin?

How to call unity C# functions from Android plugin ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("gameobjectname", "methodname", "message");
```

Comment: Thank, i already knew about this function but it never occur to me that it could be called from the java plugin, thank a lot ,

Comment: Use JavaAndroidProxy --> https://medium.com/@imstudio/unity-androidjavaproxy-b0100f20e80f OR
https://medium.com/@imstudio/unity-androidjavaproxy-b0100f20e80f